# Build failed in Android Studio. Message: The resource name shouldn't be empty, but the strings.xml is there

Tags: android, xml, gradle, android-resources

I am developing an App in Android Studio 3.3.2. By mistake, I deleted the strings.xml file which was in the default place: res/values/strings.xml.
So I simply pasted another strings.xml file from another directory in the PC to that values directory of Android Studio.
To my surprise, Android Studio cannot recognize the new strings.xml as a valid strings.xml file, although it is located in the values directory with the same name: strings.xml

When I try to build the App, it gives me:

C:\AndroidApps\LanguagePractice\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml: Error: The resource name shouldn't be empty

So, what is wrong? Is the default strings.xml file really located in another directory? Where? Do I have to modify some config file to reroute or to enable? Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Please paste the content of `strings.xml` to your question.

Comment: Solved! The variable: app_name was missing, it was: <string name="">Language Practice</string>. I simply added it, so it now is correctly: <string name="app_name">Language Practice</string>. Apparently this value is used by Android Studio to find the route of this strings.xml

Answer (score 2):

Check carefully in your strings.xml file, there must not be a string with an empty value for name attribute

Example of mistake:

```
    <string name="">Sign up</string>
```

Solution:

```
    <string name="sign_up">Sign up</string>
```